# Angular HttpClient simple GET sending preflight OPTIONS. How do I enforce my GET to remain a simple request?

Tags: angular, http, cors, http-headers

As the title states, I would like to make a simple GET request without a preflight OPTIONS, as the server does not respond with a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Header, and I am unable to change these server settings.

My code is fairly simple:

```
export interface HttpOptions {
  headers?: HttpHeaders;
  params?: HttpParams;
  observe?: 'body';
}

private getProfileDetails() {

  const httpOptions: HttpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }),
    params: new HttpParams()
      .set('service', 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200')
      .append('ticket', this.currentTicket)
      };

  this.http.get('https://server.address/val', httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
   });
}
```

For some reason the browser keeps getting the Error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

As far as I understand, this should be  a simple GET request, which does not require OPTIONS, so I'm kind of at a loss on how to go on.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: CORS is a horrible issue!  The easiest way to do this is to submit your request from your server and not from the front end.  Create a route on your backend that send the request, receives the response and sends it back to your app.

Comment: `OPTIONS` requests are made for corss-origin requests. You can't remove them, they're used by your browser to check the validity of an endpoint. Simply accept those requests in your back-end, and you should be good to go

Comment: @trichetriche - made the change but not sure why this should be a comment.  The answer to the question of how can I fix a CORS issue when I can't alter the Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings is to send the request from the back end.

Comment: Is there no other option? Right now I don't really have a back-end. I'm just running using npm run start.

Comment: @Michel you seem to have a back-end, since you make an HTTP request. Even though you use a BaaS, you should be able to edit your CORS configs.

Comment: @Farasi78 your answer doesn't actually provide an answer, but rather a general guideline. And it provides no code and fits into a comment, so that's why it should be a comment. And I won't comment on the validity of your answer, you might be right, but I'm not sharing your opinion on that matter.

Comment: I thought you meant a back-end that's serving the web-app. I have no access to change anything on the server that I'm trying to perform the GET call on

Comment: @trichetriche... okay.  But seems like it sufficiently answers "Any hints would be highly appreciated."

Comment: @Farasi78 I didn't repeat the question in the body. But the title states "How do I enforce my GET to remain a simple request?"

Comment: @Farasi78 well we're not here to talk about meta, but if you ask me, we're not here to give hints but to resolve issues. That's what I have understood in the few years I've been here, so now I'm doing the same for newcomers :)

Comment: Fair enough @trichetriche... I am very interested to see the solution that doesn't involve the backend or a proxy server being used.  I had this same trouble before and only fixed it by sending the request from the server side.  Looking forward to learning something new then! =)

Comment: Given that he makes an HTTP request to an API, I strongly doubt that you can send the exact same request without any request being sent by the front-end. Where should it go ? Which endpoint is being called ? Which headers should be sent ? Which content should be set ? Without a request, an API can't know those things. Are you sure you're talking about the same thing ? (I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just doubtful from my own experience that you can do that)

Comment: Would it be possible to have a spring-boot application that has a rest controller for a GET call, which takes the Ticket as Parameter and then calls the original GET call? (A seperate server, this spring-boot application wouldn't be hosting the webapp)

Comment: Everything is possible, the real question is will it suit you ... This seems a little bit complicated for a simple request. Could you explain why you don't have access to your API code ? Maybe we could find a solution to your issue without having a total of 3 servers !

Comment: I think as long as the request to the API goes from a server and not via a browser, it would be Ok.  I suggest your request can take the form: (Front end) myAPIService.ts ->request to myApiGetRoute on backend server.  (backend) myApiGetRoute->makes the GET request to API, receives results and returns it to myAPIService.ts.

Comment: @Farasi78 at this point, Marshal's answer seems faster, easier, and better suited than creating a whole new API for a single endpoint reach ... as for the OP, `Could you explain why you don't have access to your API code ? Maybe we could find a solution to your issue without having a total of 3 servers`

Comment: You can easily bypass this issue using a [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).

Comment: The error message cited in the question doesn’t indicate the browser is doing any preflight. It just indicates exactly what it says: There’s no Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. What made you conclude the browser is doing a preflight?

Comment: @trichetriche The people in charge of the other server refused to add the header upon asking. But I will confront them again.

Comment: @sideshowbarker My googling attempts seem to tightly connect this error with preflights. I'm kinda new to all this stuff, so maybe I just misunderstood some things.

Comment: @sideshowbarker is right, this isn't necessarily a preflight request issue, but it still is a CORS issue. The best to know your error would be to have the backend CORS configuration. And well OP, because people refuse to do their jobs, doesn't mean you should work around their lazyness and use bad practices to achieve your needs ... CORS configuration is like, the basics of an API, if they won't update their code, I suggest you go to their superviser and talk to him about that !

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explore setting up the angular-cli proxy for your API request.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: I'll look into this

Comment: While this answer might be acceptable for development purposes, I don't think you can have access to the CLI once your application has been deployed. Rather than configuring a proxy for every environment you're on, you should edit your CORS settings in your back-end.

Comment: @trichetriche I disagree. I am not simply redirecting Michel to another stackoverflow answer, therefore, it is not a trivial answer. Based on the CORS error this is a development environment; I provided a viable answer to the question as it relates to the error/information provided. Because the OP did not provide additional information on how the solution will ultimately be hosted, it would be presumptuous of me to do anything other than answer the question asked... as anything beyond that is providing my opinion/assumption as to what I believe to be best without proper information.

Comment: @Marshal I don't question your answer quality : this is a totally viable solution (although I don't agree with you as it being **the** solution, as stated in my previous comment). My "issue" is with the fact that you just provided a link to a repository wiki, and that's all. This is the kind of answer (no code, no explanation) that should be a comment. And for the rest, that's just common sense : do the modification on the side that isn't being changed at every environment. No relation to hosting, that's just best practice.

Comment: @trichetriche that is an assumption the OP has access to the server to make changes... from the information provided in the question, the OP does not have access to the server to make changes... or at least that is how I read the question. Once the project progresses further and a new issue is encountered, a revision will likely be made to the question with more information, at that point I will have the information necessary to provide a more accurate diagnosis to the issue, and yes, I will continue using best practice providing a more accurate answer. until then, its nothing but conjecture

Comment: I'm not assuming the OP has access to the server, I know he doesn't. I'm saying the best solution is to have access to it. Again, I'm not criticizing the quality of your solution, I'm just not agreeing with it. Call it my own opinion. My original comment was to say it's not an answer but a comment. My second comment was my opinion. I gave my opinion because you didn't specify the drawback of this solution in your answer. That's all. Again, you're not wrong ! I'm just disagreeing with you and giving OP all the intel he needs to make the right choice.

Comment: My approach is to provide a solution to the OP's immediate need... what if the OP is learning angular and this will never be a production app? Your "correct" answer would leave them stuck and frustrated. We can agree to disagree as it is arguing semantics at this point, I am confident through our debate the OP has the information for not only the immediate need, but the long term objective as well when the need arises. Good talk, we should definitely do it again sometime.

Comment: Yeah well if you want the quickest solution, you put your data in a JSON and request it with an `import`, and mock it with `of(data)`. That's a solution to an immediate need, why don't you offered that instead ? Plus, that's way better to understand Angular, as it also explains the hot/cold observables ... See, if you want to be absurd, I can be too. Seeing how sterile this exchange is, as you just don't like your ideas to be challenged, I do agree with you, we should stop here. But let's not do that again :D